# 18.04 - Remove icons from top bar in flashback metacity

Tags: 18.04, gnome, icons

I use flashback metacity in a 18.04. By accident I moved some icons to the top bar ... how can I remove them? If I right click I can only choose between 'Launch' and 'Properties' ... no 'Remove from top bar' option. I can 'drag' it to the Desktop ... but the icon remains at the top bar ...

[image]

Comment: Try a modified key while dragging the icon out.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Try a modified key'?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "modifier" key, e.g. <Ctrl> or <Alt> or a combination.

Comment: Ah great ... with 'ALT' + right click mouse ... I can choose 'Remove from panel'. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key while clicking the right mouse button. This will display a context menu allowing you to remove the launcher from the panel.